# printing state value for debugging

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

How can we print current state value, for debugging purposes? E.g., in code from concrete-example-1 of  http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad , how can we print the current state value after each input character is read?

```
module StateGame where

import Control.Monad.State

type GameValue = Int
type GameState = (Bool, Int)

playGame :: String -> State GameState GameValue
playGame []     = do
    (_, score) <- get
    return score

playGame (x:xs) = do
    (on, score) <- get
    case x of
       'a' | on -> put (on, score + 1)
       'b' | on -> put (on, score - 1)
       'c'      -> put (not on, score)
       _        -> put (on, score)
    playGame xs

startState = (False, 0)

main = print $ evalState (playGame "abcaaacbbcabbab") startState
```

Comment: You can try `trace` from `Debug.Trace`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For quick and dirty debugging, use `trace` from `Debug.Trace`. I often find it useful to flip the argument order and define

```
infixl 0 `debug`

debug :: a -> String -> a
debug = flip trace
```

Then you can tack the debugging to the end of the line and it's easier to comment out (and at the end remove).

For more principled logging, combine the `State` with a `Writer` and `tell` the logging messages or use `StateT s IO` if you directly want to log to a file or stderr.

Answer (score 2):

As n.m. points out there is `Debug.Trace`, but it's easy to write something yourself. However I *strongly* recommend to use this only for debugging, and to remove it for real world code. Here is an example:

```
import System.IO.Unsafe

output a b = seq (unsafePerformIO (print a))  b

(output "test" 23) * 25
-- "test"
-- 527
```

Here `output` takes an argument to print out, and a return value, behaving like a `const`, just with a side effect. `seq` is needed to force the evaluation of `print`, else laziness will prevent to print anything.

Comment: `Debug.Trace` is more explicit on this issue.